# Upgraded React - Lazy "ctor is not a function"

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I just upgraded React to 17 and I'm getting a weird error.

```
TypeError: ctor is not a function
```

[image]

My Lazy components get loaded like this

```
const Course = lazy(() => import('./containers/course'))
const Learner = lazy(() => import('./containers/learners'))
const Report = lazy(() => import('./containers/reports'))
const Home = lazy(() => import('./containers/home'))
```

Is this the problem!?

I've deleted node_modules etc so many times.

Answer (score 2):

You'll have update `react-dom` to the same version, in my case had to update both `react 17.0.2` and `react-dom 17.0.0`

Answer (score 1):

Fixed with upgrade of React-router

Comment: Which version were you using and what version did you changed to?

Answer (score 0):

This is an irrelevant to this question but for Next.js users, use `next@12.2.0` & `react@18` to avoid this error. I used `next@12.1.6` and had the same issue but after upgrading `next` version to `12.2.0`, the problem has magically solved!

Comment: This wasn't the case for me when I went from 12.1.6 -> 12.2.2

Answer (score -2):

```
Routers.map((route_val, key) => {
            var component = lazy(import(`${route_val.component}`))
            // console.log(component)
                return (
                    <AppRoute key={key}
                        path={route_val.path} 
                        exact={route_val.exact===true ? route_val.exact : null}
                        Component={component}
                        fullLayout={route_val.fullLayout}
                        hideFooter={route_val.hideFooter}
                    />
                )
            })
```